# Why there's |x| sign around $\overset n \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A_i$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: http://math.uiuc.edu/~nirobles/files453/iep_proof.pdf]

Source: http://math.uiuc.edu/~nirobles/files453/iep_proof.pdf

|-3| means 3 The function of | | is converting its inner value to nonnegative value. So why ther's $|\overset n \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A_i|$? $\bigcup$ means a union set, not a value.

Comment: Here it's the number of elements in the set

Answer (score 5):

The absolute value sign in general means a measure of magnitude.   In terms of sets, $\lvert S\rvert$ usually means "the cardinality of set $S$".   Basically the number of elements of the set (for finite sets).

Comment: In my discrete mathematics book(Susanna S. Epp), the number of elements of the set S is denoted N(S). Is |S| mentioned commonly in other discrete mathematics books? Or is it a sign in other subjects of math?

Comment: @buzzee It is the most common notation for cardinality, [although there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).  $N(S)$ is fairly common too; though usually only used with finite sets.

Answer (score 2):

|$S$| denotes the the cardinality of set $S$, not absolute value.